Filtering query where data appears in more than one column
I'm looking for help with an Access query to filter data in one table from another table where it appears in two columns.  I have the following tables:
Check_tbl



ID
C




1
123


2
456


3
789


4
FDFHSFHGF


5
SDFGDGFDS


6
ABC



source_tbl



ID
A
B
F




1
123
ABC
156.pdf


2
456

440.pdf


3

DEF
149.pdf


4
789
GHI
160.pdf


5
111

178.pdf


6

JKL
506.pdf


7


156.pdf



I need the query to return every entry in check_tbl.C which appears in source_tbl.A and source_tbl.B as well as source_tbl.F but I need duplicates removed where check_tbl.C appears in both source_tbl.A AND source_tbl.B (ie only return one of the two results)
Returned result should look like this:
results



C
F




ABC
156.pdf


456
440.pdf


789
160.pdf



since value 123 and ABC from check_tbl.C appear in source_tbl.A and source_tbl.B respectively, only one should be returned.
So far I have this:
SELECT Check_tbl.C, source_tbl.F
FROM Check_tbl
INNER JOIN source_tbl ON Check_tbl.C = source_tbl.A
UNION SELECT Check_tbl.C, source_tbl.F
FROM Check_tbl
INNER JOIN source_tbl ON Check_tbl.C = source_tbl.B;

but it doesn't filter out duplicates and return only one value where the data appears in both source_tbl.A and source_tbl.B.
If anyone can assist with this I would be grateful.

If you want the first C with the lowest ID in your result table.
The following Query simulates a ROW_NUMBER
SELECT C, F
FROM
(SELECT c1.C, s1.F,
(select count(*)
        from Check_tbl c2
INNER JOIN source_tbl s2 ON c2.C = s2.A
OR  c2.C = s2.B
        where s1.F = s2.F AND c2.ID < c1.ID
              
       ) as uniqueNumber
FROM Check_tbl C1
INNER JOIN source_tbl s1 ON c1.C = s1.A
OR  c1.C = s1.B) t1
WHERE uniqueNumber = 0;

Result:

